# Eclipse (manifest.mf) file cannot find Gradle dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, dependencies, eclipse-rcp

I have RCP multi-project application and I use Gradle to build it and it work. All classes and dependencies are compilling and I can run my app. I am using Wuff: https://github.com/akhikhl/wuff.

Problem is that I have Gradle script which copy working Manifest file for each module, generated by Gradle:

```
task copyManifest(type: Copy){
    from "build/tmp-osgi"
    into "META-INF"
}
build.finalizedBy copyManifest
```

The problem is that in Eclipse it has errors in Manifest file, saying:

```
No available bundle exports package 'packageName'
```

(ex. com.fasterxml.jackson.core;)

in module build.gradle i have:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.1'
}
```

in Eclipse's Gradle Dependencies I can see:

```
jackson-annotations-2.1.6.jar
jackson-core-2.1.6.jar
jackson-databind-2.1.6.jar
```

I build app in console by Gradle, then right-click modules -> Gradle -> Refresh Dependencies. (Thanks to it Eclipse see package imports in java files and can use them) But still manifest file cannot find them, and I cannot run/debug it through IDE.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I tell eclipse about these dependencies?